# Error when sending to browser generated PDF using iTextSharp "ERROR: Failed to load PDF document."

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5, itext, runtime

I have a function in my controller which receives an object and uses the object's data to fill a PDF. I want to send this PDF to the client so he can download it.However When I submit the form and download the generated PDF i get an error saying "ERROR: Failed to load PDF document."

Here is my code so far:

```
    private void crear_pdf_ZURICH(Seguro seguro)
    {
        var nombre_pdf = seguro.Nombre + ".pdf";

        string oldFile = Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + nombre_pdf;
        string newFile = Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + "nuevo_" + nombre_pdf;
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(oldFile))
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

                document.Open();

                //VARIABLES

                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    document.NewPage();

                    var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                    var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                    var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
                    contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
                    contentByte.BeginText();
                    contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10);

                    if (reader.NumberOfPages - (reader.NumberOfPages - i) == 1)
                    {
                        //WRITE SOME STUFF
                    }

                    else if (reader.NumberOfPages - (reader.NumberOfPages - i) == 2)
                    {
                       //WRITE SOME OTHER STUFF
                    }
                    contentByte.EndText();
                }

                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename="+newFile));
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my code working properly, it creates the PDF and I can open it without any problem, however I'm saving it on the server which can cause problems if multiple users are trying to create and download the generated PDF directly from the server.
Here is my code:

```
    private void crear_pdf_ZURICH(Seguro seguro)
    {
        var nombre_pdf = seguro.Nombre + ".pdf";

        string oldFile = Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + nombre_pdf;
        string newFile = Server.MapPath("pdf") + "\\" + "nuevo_" + nombre_pdf;


        using (var reader = new PdfReader(oldFile))
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

                document.Open();

                //VARIABLES

                for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    document.NewPage();

                    var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                    var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                    var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
                    contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
                    contentByte.BeginText();
                    contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10);

                    if (reader.NumberOfPages - (reader.NumberOfPages - i) == 1)
                    {
                       //WRITE SOME STUFF
                    }

                    else if (reader.NumberOfPages - (reader.NumberOfPages - i) == 2)
                    {
                        //WRITE SOME STUFF
                    }



                    contentByte.EndText();
                }

                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance if someone can help/explain me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the content of the PDF you are downloading from the server? It doesn't appear you are actually adding the PDF file in the response, but instead adding the file path in one of the headers. I would suspect the PDF you get back that is giving you an error is simply blank. Also, seeing as iText properly creates the PDF I don't think this issue is related to iText. I would suggest removing the tag if possible.

Comment: Then I should just return the created document? It contains images and text,nothing too fancy.